# Maintain user session in same browser in react

Tags: reactjs, session

I am working on a web app that follows dual user-role type: `Admin and Investors`. I need to disable two users (be it `admin type` or `investor type`) to log in simultaneously on a website, which is opened within the same browser but different tabs.

Irrespective of their role type, at a time, either `user A(admin)` or `user B (Investor)` can log in. I am using localStorage for this purpose, storing two different key names for admin and investor.

I am new to handling sessions this way. Also, my code is quite big and nested, so I am unable to paste the snippet out of it here.

Any help even regarding how I can follow this approach, will be appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

There are different approaches for handling sessions in client side of your web app, such as cookies and local storage.
In your case I think you should store your app user type and session ID in local storage like this:

```
s_id: admin_54759eb3c090d83494e2d80494e2d80
```

So before login app will check for s_id availability in local storage or not. Then in your app login flow you can decide to logout previous user and replace new session ID or just prevent from new login.

But I'd rather to use cookies. One benefit could be setting expiration time for session. For more info check out [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies).